# Invalid ARN prefix while creating a Terraform (ECS,ALB,CodeDeploy) template

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm learning Terraform(v1.2.4), but I'm encountering an issue when I try to incorporate AWS CodeDeploy into my testing architecture.
Everything works fine without CodeDeploy (ECS, ECR, ALB), so this is very file specific.

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
Error: Error: "load_balancer_info.0.target_group_pair_info.0.prod_traffic_route.0.listener_arns.0" (aws_alb_listener.front_end.arn) is 
an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix with aws_codedeploy_deployment_group.this, on code_deploy.tf line 40, in resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "this": 
40:listener_arns = ["aws_alb_listener.front_end.arn","aws_alb_listener.front_end2.arn"]
```

The message seems to be very obvious, but I can't figure out what's wrong, the string, the value, or what?

Here's the codeDeploy.tf file

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "this" {
  compute_platform = "ECS"
  name              = "dev-test-deploy"
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "this" {
  app_name               = aws_codedeploy_app.this.name
  deployment_group_name  = "dev-test-deploy-group"
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"
  service_role_arn       = var.codedeploy_service_role_arn

  blue_green_deployment_config {
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
  }

 terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
   action = "TERMINATE"
   termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 1
 }
}

  ecs_service {
    cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.main.name
    service_name = aws_ecs_service.main.name
  }

  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type   = "BLUE_GREEN"
  }
  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = true
    events = [ "DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE" ]
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = ["aws_alb_listener.front_end.arn","aws_alb_listener.front_end2.arn"]
  }

  target_group {
    name = "cb-target-group"
  }

  target_group {
    name = "cb-target-group2"
  }
 }
}
}
```

And here's the ALB.tf (As I found it useful)

```
# alb.tf

resource "aws_alb" "main" {
  name            = "cb-load-balancer"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets         = ["subnet-xxxx1", "subnet-xxxx2"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb.id]
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "app" {
  name        = "cb-target-group"
  port        = 80
  rotocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
    interval            = "30"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    timeout             = "3"
    path                = var.health_check_path
    unhealthy_threshold = "2"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "app2" {
  name        = "cb-target-group2"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = "3"
    interval            = "30"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    matcher             = "200"
    timeout             = "3"
    path                = var.health_check_path
    unhealthy_threshold = "2"
  }
}

# Redirect all traffic from the ALB to the target group
resource "aws_alb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.main.id
  port              = var.app_port
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app.id
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

# Redirect all traffic from the ALB to the target group
resource "aws_alb_listener" "front_end2" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.main.id
  port              = 8080
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.app2.id
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

P.S. When this is complete and fully functional, I'll be uploading the full Github repo URL here, I feel that there are not enough "real world" examples on the Internet that are truly functional and human-readable.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `aws_alb_listener.front_end.arn` and `aws_alb_listener.front_end2.arn`

Comment: Thanks for your help @jordanm , the error message just changed to "Error: Error creating CodeDeploy deployment group: InvalidTrafficRoutingConfigurationException: Production traffic route must have exactly one listener Arn", this one is more confusing than the last one

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the answer, at the beginning the formating inside the target_group_arn was wrong, as I was passing two strings, after that the error code changed, throwing this one "Error creating CodeDeploy deployment group: InvalidTrafficRoutingConfigurationException: Production traffic route must have exactly one listener Arn", it was so simple... just remove the "" as @jordanm said, and then remove the second ARN, and that's it, this is the result: listener_arns = [aws_alb_listener.front_end.arn], hope this is useful to others. Thanks

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve.